# Unexpected result when comparing dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column of type date (yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s) on a MYSQL 5.7.26 server.

When I query like this:

```
SET @THIS_YEAR = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` > year(@THIS_YEAR);
```

I am expecting all entries with date since 2019-01-01.
But I also get entries from years before.

But this query works is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` > "2019";
```

Btw this query also returns the wrong (or rather unexpected) results:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` > 2019;
```

What is the difference between these queries? Why doesnt it work with a variable or when comparing the date to an integer? I assume its somekind of auto type conversion?

Comment: A good question: What are you expecting (and why), when you compare two different types?

Comment: Let's start with the basics. Do you understand that Date fields are **not** stored as strings?  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html

Comment: Do you want a long, convoluted explanation on the differences between string and integer evaluations, or would you instead like to fix your problem? If the latter, then `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > '2019-01-01 00:00:00';` would suffice

Comment: Or `WHERE YEAR(`date`) > @THIS_YEAR`

Comment: @Strawberry, PM 77-1. I should have asked differently. I am trying to understand why comparing to a string seems to work, but comparing to an integer doesn't. Does MYSQL know that the string "2019" is supposed to be the year 2019? What exactly is it comparing in the second example with the year as an integer? For now, I am using what RiggsFolly posted

Comment: The interpreter knows nothing about the value, but will attempt to evaluate it in way appropriate to the given context, so 2019-01-01 can be interpreted as both 2017 (2019 minus 1 minus 1) and 20190101 (20 million, 190 thousand, and 100) depending on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLs implicit type conversion can be very surprising. If you want to understand the behavior of your queries, you can try to apply the type conversion rules as described in [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html). However - I failed to do that for your case. For example: For the two expressions `date > '2019'` and `date > 2019` I would apply the following rule:

> If one of the arguments is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column and the
>   other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp
>   before the comparison is performed.

But that cannot be the case, because neither the number `2019` nor the string `'2019'` can be converted to a temporal type. Here is a query, which demonstrates some implicit conversions:

```
select '2019' + interval 0 day -- implicit cast to date(time)
     , 2019 + interval 0 day
     , 20190101 + interval 0 day
     , 190101 + interval 0 day
     , '2019*01*01' + interval 0 day
     , '2019-01-01' + interval 0 day
     , '2019-01-01' + 0 -- implicit cast to numeric
     , date('2019-01-01') + 0
     , date('2018-01-01') > 2019
     , date('2018-01-01') > '2019'
;
```

Result:

```
Expression                    | Result
------------------------------|-----------
'2019' + interval 0 day       | null
2019 + interval 0 day         | null
20190101 + interval 0 day     | 2019-01-01
190101 + interval 0 day       | 2019-01-01
'2019*01*01' + interval 0 day | 2019-01-01
'2019-01-01' + interval 0 day | 2019-01-01
'2019-01-01' + 0              | 2019
date('2019-01-01') + 0        | 20190101
date('2018-01-01') > 2019     | 1
date('2018-01-01') > '2019'   | 0
```

As you see, when we try to convert `2019` or `'2019'` to a date (or datetime), we get `NULL`. Thus the conditions should also be evaluated to `NULL` and the result set would be empty. But as we know, that is not the case. Maybe I'm just wrong, assuming that `2019` and `'2019'` are constants. But then I don't know what they could mean.

So I can only make assumptions. And my assumtion is: Whenever one comparator is numeric, the other value is also converted to a numeric value. This would be the case for `date > 2019` aswell as for `date > year(@THIS_YEAR)`. In this case the date `2018-01-01` is converted to `20180101` (see the table above), which (in numeric context) is greater than `2019`. So you get rows from the year 2018.

For `date > '2019'` I can only assume, that the values are compared as strings. And `'2018-01-01'` as string is considered "smaller" than `2019`.

But even if that behavior would be properly documented, the rules are too difficult to remember, because one can hardly see any logic behind them. (I don't say - there is no logic - I just don't see any.)

So I can give you one advise: If you want to compare two incompatible types, always cast or convert them to be compatible.

```
WHERE year(date) >= year(@THIS_YEAR)
```

would be fine, since you compare two numeric values. But that is not necessery in your case and you can just use

```
WHERE date >= @THIS_YEAR
```

because `2019-01-01 00:00:00` in

```
`SET @THIS_YEAR = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";`
```

is a perfectly formatted DATETIME string and can be considered compatible with the DATETIME type. `'2019-01-01'` would be just fine aswell.

Note that if you wrapp a column into a function call (like `year(date)`) you will loose the ability to use an index on that column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul, I appreciate it. The MySQL documentation explicitly mentions only DATETIME and TIMESTAMP, so maybe type conversion for DATE is different.

Comment: @user1970122 TIMESTAMP behaves the same way: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v2c7f9qAmy6AKanoU35Gjn/0

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is one of data types.
In short words: The interpreter has a hard time knowing if your "2019" is a string or a date. So it goes by what it expects there to be.
If you store the value into a variable, it is parsed as a string, because a string is expected here. If you compare it directly, a date value is expected - and so MySQL tries to parse a date, successfully.
2019, as opposed to "2019" clearly is a number, not a date value. So that explains funny behaviour there.

Comment: "and so MySQL tries to parse a date, successfully" - How can you successfully parse `'2019'` to DATE? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Paul Spiegel Ok. That was a bit sloppy. To be honest: the MySQL implicit type conversion works in mysterious ways :-).

Answer (score 0):

This query will compare the year from @THIS_YEAR and `date`:

```
SET @THIS_YEAR = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE year(`date`) = year(@THIS_YEAR);
```

Notice `date` is wrapped in the year function. This means that you are now comparing year() to year().

This query works

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` > "2019";
```

Because the interpreter will use a character representation of `date` and perform character by character comparison: "2019-" > "2019"

This query doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` > 2019;
```

For the same reason. The interpreter will use a character representation of `date` and then compare the first character to 2019. "2" < 2019 (both in terms of human readable and numeric representation of the character 2

And this query:

```
SET @THIS_YEAR = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` > year(@THIS_YEAR);
```

Has the same problem. year() returns a number so it will again be: "2">2019

Comment: "then compare the first character to 2019. "2" < 2019" - Sorry but what are you talking about? I don't get it. This cannot be correct, since the problem is different. Please read the question again. All queries return dates from 2019. But the two "wrong" queries also return dates before 2019.

Comment: 2019 is an integer value. The interpreter will interpret the underlying date as '2019-01-01' which is a string. In string vs integer comparisons, it is treated as a string comparison with the integer representing the underlying code of the character. So the comparison would actually be: is "2" > 2019? no, so stop. Because the underlying representation of "2" (in ASCII that is 50) or whatever the table encoding is actually set, but it is less than 2019.